# Send email reminder if file not updated in 14 days

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA code within an Excel file.

I would like additional code to send a recurring email reminder if the file has not been saved within 14 days.

```vb
Sub SEND_Colleague()

    Dim MyFile As String
    
    MyFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= & MyFile
    
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    With OutlookMail
        .to = "JaneDoe@mail.com"
        .Importance = 2
        .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        
        If InStr(Filename, ".") > 0 Then
        End If
        
        .HTMLbody = "<html><body><p><font size=4>My Colleague: <p></p>" _
          & "</p><p>Please navigate to the tracking log named in the subject line of this email by clicking the link below and update the <b><i>Product</i></b> section of the log. <p></p>" _
          & "Once your updates are entered, click the form control button in <b>Cell B61</b>. The workbook will be saved to the Network shared folder and closed automatically.  Thereafter, the Outlook mail program will be initiated and a pop-up warning message will appear.  Click <u><b>Allow</b></u> and an email will be sent to the area leader.  A copy of the email can be found in your Outlook <i>Sent</i> folder.<p>" _
          & "</p><p><b><FONT COLOR=red>Note, you must return to this log and follow the steps above every 14 days until all thrid-party claims are fully adjudicated. </p></b><FONT COLOR=black>" _
          & "</p><p>Thank You</p>" _
        
        .SEND
    End With
    
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Try [DateLastModified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datelastmodified-property)?

Answer (score 2):

You want to make a check to see if the last edit date is greater than 14 days.

You can access the workbook's information with `ThisWorkbook.BuiltInDocumentProperties`, which will return a collection of the file's properties.  The date last modified should have index 12.  Then, store the value of the file's last modified date:

```
Dim DateLastModified As Date
DateLastModified = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(12)
```

And then just compare that date to today's date (and time if you wish, because `ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(12)` also contains time information).